# Conditional Expanding in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-pro, classification, arcgis-10.6, generalization, conditional

I would like to reclassify a LC map given some conditional rules (raster with 8 classes total).

Using the illustration, I would like to expand the green pixels (two distinct classes) on the white pixels (replace all the white pixels) till they meet other raster values (grey, red, blue...) without expanding these (here the grey) pixel values.

Is this possible using ArcGIS Desktop (10.6 or Pro)?

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Have you tried typing the word "expand" into the help file yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. Expand only allow growing various raster values into all others, which is not what I intend. A "conditional expand" would be the solution, allowing to specify growing values and shrinking values, with some remaining unchanged.

Comment: I think ["Nibble"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/nibble.htm) is the tool you are looking for. You'll need to create a mask where the two green classes are 1 and everything else is NoData, run Nibble, then use Con to put the grey, red, blue classes back in. I'll try to add a proper answer, if I get time and if you can edit your question and add the numeric values of the classes in.

Comment: Have a look at the [euclidean allocation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-allocation.htm) may require you to do a bit of reclassifying of your initial rasters?